Cannot resolve import net.minecraft.entity
This may sound like a noob question, but I've browsed the web for several hours now and haven't found any satisfying explanation.
I'm completely new to Minecraft modding and Forge, and I'm trying to make a simple mod just to understand the basic concepts. I had no problem with installing Forge and building the example mod, and I can play with it fine. However, when I try to import net.minecraft.entity.player.PlayerEntity which, from what I saw, is needed for any player-related functionnality, Eclipse tells me "The import net.minecraft.entity cannot be resolved" and I effectively cannot build the mod. I have this trouble for several net.minecraft imports (see my code below)
I don't understand this, especially since other net.minecraft imports seem to work fine (proof is that I can build and run the example mod, which contains several of these imports). I checked thrice that I had made no mistake while installing Forge and setting up the project, and I tried pretty much everything I could see on the web, such as running ./gradlew --refresh-dependencies then ./gradlew clean and then re-build the mod, deleting and re-importing the project in Eclipse, delete the whole project folder and restarting from zero, ...
Do I need to install anything else ? Do I just miss some Java knowledge (I'm very, very new to Java) ?
EDIT : Here is the code of the example mod :
package com.example.examplemod;

import com.mojang.logging.LogUtils;
import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.minecraft.core.registries.Registries;
import net.minecraft.world.food.FoodProperties;
import net.minecraft.world.item.BlockItem;
import net.minecraft.world.item.CreativeModeTab;
import net.minecraft.world.item.CreativeModeTabs;
import net.minecraft.world.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.world.level.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.world.level.block.Blocks;
import net.minecraft.world.level.block.state.BlockBehaviour;
import net.minecraft.world.level.material.MapColor;
import net.minecraftforge.api.distmarker.Dist;
import net.minecraftforge.common.MinecraftForge;
import net.minecraftforge.event.BuildCreativeModeTabContentsEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.event.server.ServerStartingEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.IEventBus;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.SubscribeEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.ModLoadingContext;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.config.ModConfig;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.lifecycle.FMLClientSetupEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.lifecycle.FMLCommonSetupEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.javafmlmod.FMLJavaModLoadingContext;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.DeferredRegister;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.ForgeRegistries;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.RegistryObject;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

// The value here should match an entry in the META-INF/mods.toml file
@Mod(ExampleMod.MODID)
public class ExampleMod
{
    // Define mod id in a common place for everything to reference
    public static final String MODID = "examplemod";
    // Directly reference a slf4j logger
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogUtils.getLogger();
    // Create a Deferred Register to hold Blocks which will all be registered under the "examplemod" namespace
    public static final DeferredRegister<Block> BLOCKS = DeferredRegister.create(ForgeRegistries.BLOCKS, MODID);
    // Create a Deferred Register to hold Items which will all be registered under the "examplemod" namespace
    public static final DeferredRegister<Item> ITEMS = DeferredRegister.create(ForgeRegistries.ITEMS, MODID);
    // Create a Deferred Register to hold CreativeModeTabs which will all be registered under the "examplemod" namespace
    public static final DeferredRegister<CreativeModeTab> CREATIVE_MODE_TABS = DeferredRegister.create(Registries.CREATIVE_MODE_TAB, MODID);

    // Creates a new Block with the id "examplemod:example_block", combining the namespace and path
    public static final RegistryObject<Block> EXAMPLE_BLOCK = BLOCKS.register("example_block", () -> new Block(BlockBehaviour.Properties.of().mapColor(MapColor.STONE)));
    // Creates a new BlockItem with the id "examplemod:example_block", combining the namespace and path
    public static final RegistryObject<Item> EXAMPLE_BLOCK_ITEM = ITEMS.register("example_block", () -> new BlockItem(EXAMPLE_BLOCK.get(), new Item.Properties()));

    // Creates a new food item with the id "examplemod:example_id", nutrition 1 and saturation 2
    public static final RegistryObject<Item> EXAMPLE_ITEM = ITEMS.register("example_item", () -> new Item(new Item.Properties().food(new FoodProperties.Builder()
            .alwaysEdible().nutrition(1).saturationModifier(2f).build())));

    // Creates a creative tab with the id "examplemod:example_tab" for the example item, that is placed after the combat tab
    public static final RegistryObject<CreativeModeTab> EXAMPLE_TAB = CREATIVE_MODE_TABS.register("example_tab", () -> CreativeModeTab.builder()
            .withTabsBefore(CreativeModeTabs.COMBAT)
            .icon(() -> EXAMPLE_ITEM.get().getDefaultInstance())
            .displayItems((parameters, output) -> {
                output.accept(EXAMPLE_ITEM.get()); // Add the example item to the tab. For your own tabs, this method is preferred over the event
            }).build());

    public ExampleMod()
    {
        IEventBus modEventBus = FMLJavaModLoadingContext.get().getModEventBus();

        // Register the commonSetup method for modloading
        modEventBus.addListener(this::commonSetup);

        // Register the Deferred Register to the mod event bus so blocks get registered
        BLOCKS.register(modEventBus);
        // Register the Deferred Register to the mod event bus so items get registered
        ITEMS.register(modEventBus);
        // Register the Deferred Register to the mod event bus so tabs get registered
        CREATIVE_MODE_TABS.register(modEventBus);

        // Register ourselves for server and other game events we are interested in
        MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(this);

        // Register the item to a creative tab
        modEventBus.addListener(this::addCreative);

        // Register our mod's ForgeConfigSpec so that Forge can create and load the config file for us
        ModLoadingContext.get().registerConfig(ModConfig.Type.COMMON, Config.SPEC);
    }

    private void commonSetup(final FMLCommonSetupEvent event)
    {
        // Some common setup code
        LOGGER.info("HELLO FROM COMMON SETUP");

        if (Config.logDirtBlock)
            LOGGER.info("DIRT BLOCK >> {}", ForgeRegistries.BLOCKS.getKey(Blocks.DIRT));

        LOGGER.info(Config.magicNumberIntroduction + Config.magicNumber);

        Config.items.forEach((item) -> LOGGER.info("ITEM >> {}", item.toString()));
    }

    // Add the example block item to the building blocks tab
    private void addCreative(BuildCreativeModeTabContentsEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getTabKey() == CreativeModeTabs.BUILDING_BLOCKS)
            event.accept(EXAMPLE_BLOCK_ITEM);
    }

    // You can use SubscribeEvent and let the Event Bus discover methods to call
    @SubscribeEvent
    public void onServerStarting(ServerStartingEvent event)
    {
        // Do something when the server starts
        LOGGER.info("HELLO from server starting");
    }

    // You can use EventBusSubscriber to automatically register all static methods in the class annotated with @SubscribeEvent
    @Mod.EventBusSubscriber(modid = MODID, bus = Mod.EventBusSubscriber.Bus.MOD, value = Dist.CLIENT)
    public static class ClientModEvents
    {
        @SubscribeEvent
        public static void onClientSetup(FMLClientSetupEvent event)
        {
            // Some client setup code
            LOGGER.info("HELLO FROM CLIENT SETUP");
            LOGGER.info("MINECRAFT NAME >> {}", Minecraft.getInstance().getUser().getName());
        }
    }
}

And the code I'm trying to write should look more or less like this, I'm trying to create a block that damages the player when they right-click it (the Eclipse error messages are in comments) :
package com.example.examplemod;

import net.minecraft.util.ActionResultType; //The import net.minecraft.util.ActionResultType cannot be resolved
import net.minecraft.block.Block; // The import net.minecraft.block cannot be resolved
import net.minecraft.block.BlockPos; //The import net.minecraft.block cannot be resolved
import net.minecraft.entity.player.PlayerEntity; //The import net.minecraft.entity cannot be resolved
import net.minecraft.util.math.BlockRayTraceResult; // The import net.minecraft.util.math cannot be resolved
import net.minecraft.util.Hand; //The import net.minecraft.util.Hand cannot be resolved



public class DamagerBlock extends Block { //Cannot resolve Block to a type
    
    /*CONSTRUCTOR*/
    
    @Override
    public static ActionResultType onBlockActivated(BlockState state, World worldIn,
            BlockPos pos, PlayerEntity player, Hand handIn,
BlockRayTraceResult hit) { //Several errors about all these types that cannot be resolved
        
        /*DAMAGE THE PLAYER*/
        
        return ActionResultType.CONSUME; //ActionResultType cannot be resolved to a variable
    }

}

P.-S. I'm using Forge 1.20.6

It would help if you posted the code that Eclipse is complaining about, as well as your actual import statements. The more detail you can supply in your question, the better your chances of getting a decent answer because then people don't have to spend time making wild guesses or trying to read your mind.
